# Lenovo 14-pin PSU confusion

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, connector, atx, lenovo-desktop-computer

I have a Lenovo IdeaCentre from 2014 as my main rig. I was about to replace the GPU (a GT 705) with a GTX650Ti that I have from my friend's old rig. I realised it needed a PCIx power, and I have a Corsair VS350 PSU that I intend to replace the original Lite-on PSU with. The original one has a 14-pin connector instead of the 20-pin ATX. I bought a converter for this, but the OG one has an extra 4 pins. The connector is on the other side of the mobo, and is labeled `ATX_12V`. However, I'm not sure if the pinout is the same as the 4-pin extension on the ATX connector. This connxn. is not shown on any pinout of the PSU. Could someone assist me with this? Thanks,